# Synchronized blocks and Locks

Tags: java, locking, nonblocking, synchronized

I have two threads and I am currently doing locking using an Object's notify() and wait() methods inside Synchronized blocks. I wanted to make sure that the main thread is never blocked so I used a boolean this way (only relevant code provided.)

```
//Just to explain an example queue
private Queue<CustomClass> queue = new Queue();

//this is the BOOLEAN
private boolean isRunning = false;

private Object lock;

public void doTask(){
       ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            //the invocation of the second thread!!
            service.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                       while(true){
                            if (queue.isEmpty()){
                                synchronized (lock){
                                     isRunning = false;   //usage of boolean
                                     lock.wait();
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                process(queue.remove());
                            } 
                       }
                });

}

//will be called from a single thread but multiple times.
public void addToQueue(CustomClass custObj){


       queue.add(custObj);
       //I don't want blocking here!!
       if (!isRunning){
           isRunning = true;      //usage of BOOLEAN!     
           synchronized(lock){
           lock.notify();
           }
       }
}
```

Does anything seems wrong here? thanks.
**Edit:** 
Purpose: This way when add() will be called the second time and more, it won't get blocked on notify(). Is there a better way to achieve this non blocking behavior of the main thread?

Comment: Hmm, why don't you use a `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: Mark `isRunning` as `volatile`. It is accessed from two threads.

Comment: This is more a question for CodeReview.

Comment: The problem is that `isRunning` could be cached by the worker thread running on a separate core and updated on that core but not pushed back to the core that the main thread is running on... `volatile` puts in a memory barrier that stops that happening.

Comment: isRunning is the variable you are changing inside the synchronized block and you are not blocking that, you are blocking some object instead, I don;t understand the purpose !

Comment: Also - Java doesn't implement closures properly i.e. I don't think this will compile as the anonymous inner class cannot access `isRunning`. `isRunning` should be set using a method call.

Comment: Why not use `BlockingQueue`? You don't have to lock & signal by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you do not show the `addToQueue` code I am fairly certain that this code will not work properly, as you are accessing the shared queue (which is not thread-safe) without any synchronization.

```
process(queue.remove());
```

Instead of trying to make your custom queue work (I doubt that your plan with the boolean flag is possible), save the time and work and use one of the [BlockingQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) provided in the JDK.

Comment: Yes. Now I intend to use LinkedBlockingQueue.

Comment: Oi - shame on me : Forgot to scroll down in the code section. (.

Answer (score 0):

The Queue is not synchronized and therefore the above code can suffer from the lost wake-up call typical for conditional variables and monitors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem
For example, here is a problematic sequence:
At the beginning of the run the Q is empty and isRunning is false. 
Thread 1 (t1) checks if Q is empty (which is true) and then stops running. 
Than Thread 2 (t2) starts running and execute the addToQ method. 
and then t1 continues running and waits on the lock although the Q is not empty. 
If you want a non-blocking solution you can use the non-blocking Q java is offering (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)Of course, you can use java own blockingQueue, but this is blocking.